# Double Linked List: compile class error

Tags: c++, list

I have a problem. 
I wrote a short list program in C++, using templates. (I wrote part of the code that reproduce the error, according to the MCVE)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename H> class Node{
protected:
  H *value;
  Node<H> *next, *prev;
public:
  Node(H *value) {
    this->value = NULL;
    if (value)
        this->value = new H(*value);
    next = prev = NULL;
}
Node(H value, Node<H> *next) {
    this->value = NULL;
    if (value)
        this->value = new H(*value);
    this->next = next;
    prev = NULL;
} 

 void setPrev(Node<H> *prev) {
    this->prev = prev;
  }
 }

template <typename H>class DoubleLinkedList {
private:
Node<H> *head, *last;
public:
 DoubleLinkedList() {
    last = new Node<H>(NULL);
    head = new Node<H>(NULL, last);
    last->setPrev(head);
}

};

int main() {
   DoubleLinkedList<int> *list = new DoubleLinkedList<int>();
   return 0;
 }
```

However, when I try to compile it, I get a compile class template error, marking the lines of the constructor method of DoubleLinkedList class.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Additionally to the missing [MCVE] you should try to reproduce the error with some english error messages. You can do so e.g. using a c++ standard online compiler like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: English is better than it needs to be. Do not link to files that are necessary to interpret the question. Links rot and the question becomes useless when they do. Minimize the files down to what is need to to compile and demonstrate the problem (that [mcve] thing again) and then add them directly to the question. The beauty of minimizing the code you show is odds are great that by the time you've reached the minimum code you've exposed the problem and have some idea how to fix it.

Comment: Warning: In `void Inserisci(Nodo<H> *temp, H val)` `H val` is pass by value. That means it is a copy that is only valid within this call to the function. `Nodo<H> *n = new Nodo<H>(&val, temp, temp->getNext());` stores a pointer to this local copy inside the linked list, and the linked list will outlive the function call resulting in what's known as a dangling pointer. A pointer that points to a no longer valid memory location.

Comment: Ah. But it seems the function does not accept a pointer and that's likely your problem right there.

Comment: Strongly recommend against `H *value;` You almost certainly do not want `value` to be a pointer, and on the rare occasions you do then the type provided as `H` should be a `pointer`. Avoid having to dynamically allocate memory unless something forces you to.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've correct this, but I still get the same error

Comment: When I take your current code and change `Node(H value, Node<H> *next)` to `Node(H * value, Node<H> *next)`, The code compiles and may run correctly (haven't tested it). Example:  https://ideone.com/iag5wX

Comment: Yeah! I've correct this and now works! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I take your current code and change Node(H value, Node *next) to Node(H * value, Node *next), The code compiles and may run correctly        (haven't tested it). Example: ideone.com/iag5wX – user4581301